# How to use django-push-notifications with an APNS .p8 certificate

Tags: django, apple-push-notifications, pem, django-push-notifications, p8

Has anybody used the django-push-notifications library recently?

It looks useful, but it seems like it needs an update.  The documentation at https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications/blob/master/docs/APNS.rst only discusses how to generate the required .pem file from a .p12 certificate, but now Apple gives you a .p8 certificate.

Any ideas how to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this has now been documented with [this change](https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications/pull/566/files).

> **APNS_AUTH_KEY_PATH**: Absolute path to your APNS signing key file for Token-Based Authentication . Use this instead of APNS_CERTIFICATE if you are using .p8 signing key certificate.
>
> **APNS_AUTH_KEY_ID**: The 10-character Key ID you obtained from your Apple developer account
>
> **APNS_TEAM_ID**: 10-character Team ID you use for developing your company’s apps for iOS.